# issue with adding library in android studio [ Configuration with name 'default' not found.]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I am facing an issue while adding project library in android studio 
here is my project structure

MyApp 
- app 
- libraries 
-- library

in root settings.gradle:

```
include ':app' include 'libraries:library'
```

And in app gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile project(':libraries:library')
}
```

and I'm getting this error:

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `library` module  has its own `build.gradle` file inside it. It happens when any of your module inside the project doesn't have its build.gradle file.

Your Project structure should look like this

```
|+----Your_Project
  |+---libraries
  |   +--library
  |      +--src
  |      +--res
  |      --build.gradle
  |      --AndroidManifest.xml
  |+---app
       +--src
       +--res
       --build.gradle
  |---settings.gradle
  |---build.gradle
```

Answer (score 0):

I opened up the search all command in my project using the double shift hotkey and searched for import module.

I found it at the bottom of the list and clicked it. This worked differently (not to mention properly) from adding a module from the module settings screen.